# SUMAR MONTO EN COLUMNAS AÑOS

Tags: sql-server-2008

Necesito seleccionar el monto en columnas "años"

Por Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que he realizado:

```sql
SELECT CLIENTE,
CASE
WHEN YEAR(FECHA)=2021 THEN '2021'
END AS '2021'
FROM CLIENTES
```

Comment: Ya intentaste o investigaste acerca de la función **SUM**?

Comment: Mas bien te recomiendo que le eches una revisada a `PIVOT` [Pivot](https://www.sqlshack.com/es/revision-del-operador-relacional-y-descripcion-general-de-pivot-y-unpivot-estatico-y-dinamico-de-sql/), es estático, pero con consultas puedes hacerlo dinámico.